# Atualizar variável de data numa Consulta SQL, mensalmente

Tags: sql, sql-server, data

Tenho um projeto de Power BI (com banco de dados SQL Server) onde eu inseri uma consulta SQL com um filtro de data.

A ideia é filtrar `variavel_data >= '2022-02-01'` se eu estiver querendo resultados de Fevereiro e adiante. Mas como esse dashboard vai ser mensal, e resultados de meses passados não serão usados, eu queria um jeito no código SQL de alterar para o mês e ano atual, com o dia '01' no final.

Existe um jeito mais fácil de mudar o ano e mês baseado na data do computador?

O filtro é assim: `variavel_data >= '2022-02-01'` 
E eu tentei isso: `variavel_data >= convert(datetime, convert(year(getdate()), month(getdate()), varchar(01)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segue uma possível solução!

```
USE [MASTER]
GO 

/*SQL >= 2012 | Tipo: DATE */

SELECT 'DATEADD(D,1,EOMONTH(GETDATE(),-1))' , DATEADD(D,1,EOMONTH(GETDATE(),-1))
SELECT 'DATEADD(D,1,EOMONTH(GETDATE(), 0))' , DATEADD(D,1,EOMONTH(GETDATE(), 0)) 
SELECT 'DATEADD(D,1,EOMONTH(GETDATE(), 1))' , DATEADD(D,1,EOMONTH(GETDATE(), 1))  

/*SQL >= 2008 | Tipo: DATETIME */
SELECT 'DATEADD(M, 0, DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, GETDATE()), 0))', DATEADD(M, 0, DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
SELECT 'DATEADD(M, 1, DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, GETDATE()), 0))', DATEADD(M, 1, DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
SELECT 'DATEADD(M, 2, DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, GETDATE()), 0))', DATEADD(M, 2, DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]